# how not process the first line using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to change the `ps` virtual memory size output from KiB to Mib and add sign to it, but neither want to change the header（first line），nor remove it from the result.

example
from

```
PID COMMAND            VSZ
    9 bash              6304
  537 ps                7476
```

to

```
PID COMMAND            VSZ
    9 bash              6MB
  537 ps                7MB
```

Comment: awk tracks the record number in the `NR` variable.  You can skip your processing if `NR == 1`.

Comment: I have tried like ```ps -o pid,vsz | awk ' NR!=1 ($2=$2"MB") ' ``` which the first line become ```PID VSSZMB``` and also ```ps -o pid,vsz | awk ' {if(NR==1){ print } else {$2=$2"mb"} } '```  which only prints out the first line ```PID VSZ```

Comment: I try out my answer, use ```ps -o pid,vsz | awk 'NR ==1 {print}  NR>1 ($2=$2"MB") ' ```

Comment: `NR!=1 ($2=$2"MB")` says "append `MB` to `$2`; then concatenate that and the string `1`, then compare result against `NR`". Perhaps you meant to use `{ .. }` instead of `( ... )` ? `NR!=1 {$2=$2"MB"} 1`

Comment: `| tail +2` to remove the first line

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372388/

Answer (score 1):

1. the default implicit print only happens if no action is provided
2. `(...)` is not the same as `{...}`

```
NR!=1 ($2=$2"MB")
```

- whole line is treated as a single pattern
- concatenate `$2` and `"MB"` and assign to `$2`
- concatenate `1` and result of parenthesised expression (ie. value of `$2`)
- test if `NR` is not equal to that

As `NR` is always a number and `"MB"` is not, the test will always succeed. (ie. the pattern matches)

No action has been provided, so the default print is done.

```
{ if(NR==1){ print } else {$2=$2"mb"} }
```

- whole line is treated as single action
- no pattern provided, so this action is performed for every record
- record is (explicitly) printed if `NR` equals `1`
- otherwise value of `$2` is updated - there is no default print

---

Probably you want something like:

```
NR!=1 { $2 = int($2/1024) "MB" }
      { print }
```

or equivalently:

```
NR!=1 { $2 = int($2/1024) "MB" } 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I try out and found the answer `ps -o pid,vsz| awk 'NR ==1 {print}  NR>1 ($2=int($2/1024)"MB") '`

and I have no idea why this work.

Comment: That is definitely not the answer, it's doing at least 3 things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
input00='PID COMMAND            VSZ
    9 bash              6304
  537 ps                7476'

printf '%s\n' "$input00" | gcat -b
printf '%s\n' "$input00" |
```

> ```
> mawk 'NR==!_ ||        sub(__  = "[0-9]+[[:space:]]*$", 
>                 int(substr(___ = $+_,
>                      match(___, __), RLENGTH) / 4^5) "MB")^_' FS='\n' | gcat -b
> ```

```
     1  PID COMMAND            VSZ
     2      9 bash              6304
     3    537 ps                7476
```

> 

```
     1  PID COMMAND            VSZ
     2      9 bash              6MB
     3    537 ps                7MB
```

This approach preserves the random combination of spaces and tabs from the input, other than trailing ones.

*this performs mere integer truncation instead of proper rounding. adjust accordingly if needed.*

but if you don't care to preserve all the spaces and tabs, then it's simply :

> ```
> mawk 'NR==1 ? NF=NF : $NF = int($NF/4^5) "MB"'
> ```

```
 1  PID COMMAND VSZ
 2  9 bash 6MB
 3  537 ps 7MB
```